# Too many Events are loaded when calendar is initialized from json

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-3

I have the following code...

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    // page is now ready, initialize the calendar...
    var calendar = $('#fullCalendar').fullCalendar({
        // put your options and callbacks here
        // height: 600,
        // aspectRatio: 2,
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,basicWeek,basicDay'
        },
        navLinks: true, // can click day/week names to navigate views
        editable: false,
        eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
        events: <?php echo $myjson ?>,
```

This loads all of the events, not just the ones needed for the monthly view.  I cannot figure out how to set the start and end params to limit the event loading.  I would greatly appreciate some insight on this.

Comment: Read https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/events-json-feed, it explains what you should do. You need to tell fullCalendar a URL where it can go to get the event data (rather than just injecting the event data directly into the calendar). That way, fullCalendar will send a separate HTTP request to that URL every time it needs to load events, and it will automatically send the correct start and end dates for the current view, each time it makes a request. All you have to do is make a script (e.g. `events.php`) which reads those start/end parameters and uses them to return the correct set of events.

Comment: I did this.  It seems that the issue is the JSON file dataset is too large to parse.  When I just create the JSON path and try to view the file in the website, I get the internal error message.  It works for a smaller JSON file dataset.

Comment: You need to look at your log file on the server to find the exact error